# Using return in a while loop

Tags: python, return, gpio

In my continuing quest for more control, I need to put an interrupt based on an end stop GPIO pin switch event.

I am using return make sure a controller change is picked up when sent, was thinking that a pin 11 event would also do the same. But the pin event is not stopping the motor.

```
GPIO.setup(GPIO_SW1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.RISING)

def MotorControl(direction,fspeed,bspeed):
  print "motor control: bspeed: " + str(bspeed) +"% : fspeed: " + str(fspeed) + " %"
  while not  GPIO.event_detected(11):
    if direction == "fwd":
       print "I am forward"
       bck.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
       fwd.ChangeDutyCycle(fspeed)
       time.sleep(0.01)
       return  
    if direction == "bwd":
       print "iam backwards"
       bck.ChangeDutyCycle(bspeed)
       fwd.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
       time.sleep(0.01)
       return     
  else:
     bck.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
     fwd.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
  return
```

Comment: A `return` will not only exit the loop but the entire function.  Did you maybe want a `break`?

Comment: @user2097159 or `elif` :)

Comment: Not sure, I read that it is possible to put else: in w while loop, not elif?

Comment: @user tried break instead of return, but can only use in the main loop it seems, or did you mean, break instead of else:?

Comment: Replace the two `return`s in the loop with `break`s then remove the `else:`

Comment: @user thanks tried that, but still nothing on the gpio pin 11 event. I do know the hardware is working...

Comment: The issue here appears to be that the `else` clause isn't being executed. This is because when `direction` is either `"fwd"` or `"bwd"` the loop is terminated at the first iteration, either by the `return` statements you have in here or the `break` statements you were advised to replace them with. Terminating a loop with `break` ensures that the `else` clause won't be executed.

Comment: Also, surely you just need to set the duty cycle once, not every time you have tested for the GPIO change you are looking for? Or am I misunderstanding?